# Show that cycloid is piecewise smooth

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, curves

Let be
$$
γ(t) = (a(t−sin t), a(1−cost)).
$$
Consider
$γ : [0, 4π] → \mathbb R^2$. I want to show that $γ(t)$ is piecewise smooth.

I know that $γ'(t)= (a(1-cos(t)), asen(t))$, and $γ'(t)$ is continous for all $t$

I know that $γ(t)$ is not smooth, because $γ'(t)$ is $0$ for $t=2\pi,0,4\pi$

But how do I find a partition P that $γ(t): [t_{i-1},t_i]$ be smooth.

Comment: Well... I think that you have to partition to every point that the function is not smooth (in your example $3$ in total).

Comment: the definition of partition includes the extremes of the interval, and in this case, the extremes are the points that function is not smooth